# python: list index out of range in matrix multiplication

Tags: python, list, function, matrix, matrix-multiplication

i'm new to python,so i'm sorry if this is a silly question. This is a legit program for matrix multiplication but i don't understand why it's throwing the error list index out of range for my input?

```
def matmult(a,b):
 product=[[0 for i in range(len(a))] for j in range(len(b[0]))]
 for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b[0])):
      for k in range(len(b)):
        product[i][j]+=a[i][k]*b[k][j]
 return product
matmult([[1,1]],[[3,4],[5,6]])
```

Comment: For whoever downvoted the question, the person is asking after specifically stating that she is *new* to python. Please don't be so hostile. We all too were new once upon a time and made such mistakes.

Comment: @SagarBHathwar thank you :)

Comment: @SagarBHathwar it's not working for matrices that aren't square

Comment: Apologies. I've corrected my answer. I had switched the initialization order. Also, ensure `len(a[0]) == len(b)` so that the function doesn't return junk for non-conforming matrices

Answer (score 1):

It's because of `product=[]`. The product list is empty but you are indexing it. That is throwing the `IndexError: list index out of range` error

Do this instead

`product = [[0 for i in range(len(b[0]))] for j in range(len(a))]`

This will pre-allocate space for the product so that you can index it